# I can't create new account via rpc with personal_newAccount method

Tags: json-rpc

I want to create new account via rpc

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8545 -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_newAccount","params":["1234567890"],"id":11}'
```

but this command return this error instead

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":11,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"local keystore not used"}}
```

Other commands work well i.e.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8545 -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_listAccounts","params":[],"id":1}'

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":    ["0xcd88f3430a2e01e61554e655719e0f92d3e1ba37","0xead50c98f7a46aa243d34b8c26a67ebbd0eb9c6b","0xbee2a7c80f82956b5aee1fd16591d27264fc501d","0x49cfae6be4a0441cf0795c74d6ea17dea7d94d34","0x50b4dbf82d2f318b8ec4c6051f8b52b116264c52","0x5ffbc4265138bb6aeb7e8e6504c7914ea4d13a4c","0x9455771da1814127c57e03adbe4421354cccc9f6","0x433c71a134f2f068c7990a33da19d56a49b55c5a"]}
```

So why method  `personal_newAccount` can't see local keystore? What do I do wrong? Please help

PS

```
geth account new
```

works absolutely fine, no errors, I can create account. Only rpc throw this damn error.

And command line I used to launch geth

```
 geth --goerli --syncmode "light" --http --signer=/home/alex/.clef/clef.ipc --http.api "personal,eth,web3"
```

Comment: What is the command line used to launch geth?

Comment: @Ismael geth --goerli --syncmode "light" --http --signer=/home/alex/.clef/clef.ipc --http.api "personal,eth,web3"

Comment: @Ismael any ideas why that error happen?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used clef to sign, I'll look there, but the rest seems fine, personal api is enabled.

Comment: @Ismael what signer do you use?

Comment: I manage accounts with hdwallet provider on the programming side. After reading the [tutorial](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/clef/tutorial) it seems that if you enable geth integration with clef you have to use clef for account management. They have [account_new](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/clef/apis#account_new) JSON-RPC command to create an account.

Comment: yeah, its exactly what I did

Comment: If you have solved your problem it will be nice to write an answer so it can help others in similar situation.

Comment: @Ismael not yet. As workaround I used php shelexec for simple command `geth account new`. But that is not very good solution. Maybe problem in clef and need to use another signer but can't find it yet

Comment: Any news? Bumping in this error too

Comment: @chab42 unfortunately no. I had use system command via php, execute and parse result.

Comment: @OleksandrIY I fixed it on Polygon nodes (and mumbai) by adding `disable-bor-wallet = false` ; this value is now true by default since this upgrade https://forum.polygon.technology/t/bor-heimdall-mainnet-upgrade-v0-3-0-action-required/10691